# Wordpress adds extra width to post images container boxes

Tags: images, attachments

when I insert an image into a post, the `<div>` that contains that image (and thus any caption) is set to be wider that the image itself.

For example, I have added an image that is 211px wide. The `<div>` that houses the image has an element style of 221px.

Is there a way, other than using javascript, to remove that, and have the box of equal width to the containing image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something I wrote a while ago: ['Adjusting Caption Frame Width'](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/adjust-caption-frame-width)

Comment: Well done Squire. It's mental that this even happens.